# jQuery Uncaught Typerror: Property '$' of Object is not a Function

Tags: jquery, content-management-system, syntax-error

I recieve an error (`Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function`) when trying to run the following jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.login').click(function(){
    $.getJSON('https://www.cloudflare.com/api_json.html', $('form').serialize())
  });
});
```

I do not receive this error on [the test page](http://domainmanager.tech-bytes.org) I set up, I only receive it on [my actual site](http://tech-bytes.org/domain-manager). I've tried replacing my first line of code with

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
```

because other posts suggested my CMS was loading jQuery in *no-conflict* mode, and it just returned a different error (`Uncaught ReferenceError: jquery is not defined`). Does anyone have any helpful suggestions?

Comment: I have the following code in my header: `<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>`. That should load jQuery right? How should I verify that it is loading for sure? There are also several other scripts on the site that are using jQuery and seem to be working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it should be `jQuery` not `jquery`.

jQuery variables are case sensitive.

You have used `jquery(document).ready(function($){` small case `q`, it should be `jQuery(document).ready(function($){`

You can shorten it to

```
jQuery(function($){
            $('.submit-login-info').click(function(){
                $.getJSON('https://www.cloudflare.com/api_json.html', $('.logininfo').serialize())
            });
        });
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked, but now I get a different, unrelated error: _XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.cloudflare.com/api_json.html?tkn=&email=&z=&a=rec_load_all. Origin http://www.tech-bytes.org is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin._

Comment: Should this posted under a different post since it is unrelated to the original issue? Also, should answers that were intended to be helpful but didn't actually solve the issue be downvoted, or are only answers not intended to help supposed to be downvoted?

Comment: This is a very common error faced with newbies in Ajax, you can search for `Same Origin Policy` with Ajax. There are lot of questions within SO itself regarding this

Comment: The same origin policy prevents the browsers from making ajax calls to different domain than from which the page was loaded. One of the solution is to use jsonp

Comment: I tried using JSONP, but cannot figure out how to do it. I tried adding _&callback=mycallback_ because that's what [the CloudFlare API] (http://www.cloudflare.com/docs/client-api.html) specified (I think it wants somethign specified in place of mycallback, but I am not sure what) and also _&callback=?_ because that's what I kept reading on other posts. Do  I need to specify that I am trying to use JSONP and not JSON somehow, or am I doing something else wrong? I have the code stored [here](domainmanager.tech-bytes.org).

Comment: I would recommend you ask a separate question about jsonp with cloudflare, and post a link here so that I also can have a look

Comment: Alright, am I doing everything correctly; would what I've done generally work as JSONP, and it is just something with CloudFlare?

Comment: In generally a jsonp will look like `$.getJSON('https://www.cloudflare.com/api_json.html?callback=?', $('.logininfo').serialize())`, I haven't gone through cloudflare api yet

Comment: I posted a new question about this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15104981/same-origin-policy-error-when-using-jquery-jsonp-with-cloudflare-api).

Answer (score 1):

First of all make sure `jQuery` js is loaded.

Also check for other javascript library that are conflicting with `jQuery $`.

And use `jQuery.noConflict();`

**Official Document** : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Answer (score 1):

JS is case-sensitive:

```
jquery(document).ready(function($){
 ^__ This should be capitalized
```

Answer (score 1):

In your source code, jQuery is all lowercase, "jquery". That seems to be your issue. Change it to "jQuery" and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 

    $('a[href=#top]').click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
        return false;
    });

});     
</script>
```

Then you can use $ withing the scope of that function, without conflicting it with other library outside the scope