# Same Origin Policy Error when using jQuery JSONP with CloudFlare API

Tags: api, jquery, getjson, same-origin-policy

I recieve an error `(XMLHttpRequest cannot load https:// www.cloudflare.com/api_json.html?tkn=&email=&z=&a=rec_load_all&callback=%3F. Origin http:// domainmanager.tech-bytes.org is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.)` (spaces inserted in URLs due to Stack Overflow link limit) when trying to send a JSONP request via jQuery to CloudFlare. The [CloudFlare API](http://www.cloudflare.com/docs/client-api.html) states that you can *ask for a JSONP callback by appending a `&callback=mycallback` parameter*. I am not sure if I am supposed to replace mycallback with something, I tried replacing it with ? as that is what some other resources said, or if I have to do some other modifications to [my code](http://domainmanager.tech-bytes.org).

Comment: what's in the console? `200 status`.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. I posted what was in the console above, unless you mean a different console? I also posted the address where I was storing the code, you may be able retrieve the information there.

Comment: i checked your json api url and `that is succeeding status comes with 200`

Comment: What? I realize both servers are returning a successfully HTTP code (200) but that's not what my problem is. If you are failing to reproduce that problem, then try checking the console in Chrome, because not all browsers enforce/implement Same Origin Policy the same way, and some don't use it at all.

Answer (score 1):

Try in this way for cross domain request.

```
  $.ajax({ url: "yourUrl",
    data:{paramName1: JSON.stringify(paramValue1),paramName2: JSON.stringify(paramValue2)},

        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       dataType: "jsonp",
      success: function(data) {
          alert(data.d);
       },
       error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           alert(textStatus);
       }
    });
```

Comment: +1 for the dataType:"jsonp",  but I don't think you usually need the JSON.stringify for the parameters (unless they are objects you wish to serialize),  and I believe error callbacks will not triggered for jsonp requests (might as well add the handler, but don't be surprised if its not activated).

Comment: Is there a way to use JSONP while still using the .getJSON shorthand method, or do I have to use the .ajax method? I was reading the [API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) and saw they had an example using .getJSON to retrieve data from the Flickr JSONP API, but couldn't figure out how to apply it to my code, or how it differed from a regular JSON request.

Comment: @NGWMark In .getJSON we do not declare Datatype as jsonp. And always try to use .ajax method by this you get more control over your request.

Comment: @Iftah ya you are right there is no need of JSON.stringify() method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CORS for this purpose.

Example code:

```
jQuery.support.cors = true; 

function CrosDom_ajax(url) {
        if (window.XDomainRequest
        && $.browser.msie
        && $.browser.version < 10) {
        xdr = new XDomainRequest();
        if (xdr) {
            xdr.onload = function () {
               alert(xdr.responseText);

            };
            xdr.open("get", url);
            xdr.send();
        }
        }
        else {
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                success: function (response) {


                },
                error: function (data) {
                }
            });
         }
    }
```

Also you need to Write the following code in server side, to allow cross domain access

```
Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```